# hint.css not working with input tags

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I was trying to use [hint.css](https://github.com/chinchang/hint.css) in my registration form but its not working the tooltip is working fine with other tags but is not working with `<input>` tags
here is my part of html:

```
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hint.css/1.3.2/hint.css" rel="stylesheet">
<p>
<a class="hint--bottom" data-hint="This is a tooltip">Hello</a>
</p>
<input name="name" value="" class="hint--bottom" data-hint="This is a tooltip"/>
```

demo [here](http://jsbin.com/pugocapi/3/edit)

or please suggest any alternative tooltip which supports input tag.

*PS:Please do not use jsfiddle for your demo as it takes takes too long to open on my slow connection.*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it won't work, but try wrapping it in a span tag.

```
<span class="hint--bottom" data-hint="This is a tooltip!"><input name="name" value=""/></span>
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to make it onfocus ?

Comment: It's not working on input element because input elements can't have pseudo elements.

Comment: any alternative which I can use in input tags ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pugocapi/6/edit Here'is a stupid workaround, so maby it help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you **should use div or span to achieve this with input tag**. Because hint.css uses pseudo elements
 like :after and :before in their style sheets which is not supported by [Replaced Elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements) (input tags). This is already reported as an issue in [Github](https://github.com/chinchang/hint.css/issues/49)

More about pseudo elements on input tag in [Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)